# Optimal way to store references to multiple tables in a single row?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, erd

this is a question in regards to Database Modelling, and I am using mySQL for this project.

I have three tables named service[1-3] (example names), each containing information of a service(think repair-service, rebuilding-service, fine-tuning-service, etc..). These three tables hold different information, and do *not* fit together in a single table.

**I want to be able to track which customers have had *what* service performed, and also if they have been billed for that service.**

So, assume that I already have a database entity called *customer*.

Now, I think that I may want to create a fourth table named tbl_rendered_services with foreign keys pointing to the relevant instances of that service, as well as to the relevant customer.

That table would look like this:

```
tbl_rendered_services
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| id | customer  | service1_ref | service2_ref | service3_ref | billed   |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 1  | 1         | 00001        | NULL         | NULL         | 0        |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 2  | 1         | NULL         | 10002        | NULL         | 0        |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 3  | 2         | NULL         | NULL         | 20003        | 1        |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 4  | 2         | NULL         | 10003        | NULL         | 0        |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
```

Using this table, I can generate a bill for a given customer by the query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_rendered_services WHERE customer = 2 AND billed = 0;
```

Which returns:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| id | customer  | service1_ref | service2_ref | service3_ref | billed   |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 4  | 2         | NULL         | 10003        | NULL         | 0        |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
```

Now, I think this seems like a reasonable solution so far, but my question is:

**Is there any better way of doing this?**

I can't think of any, but I feel like there might be one I'm not seing?

Thank you for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: My suggestion is to have a look about MySQL performance when the data gets really big (talking about 10^9 data size). Maybe it would be better to store 2 more columns in tbl_rendered_services and save some rows. Imagine a customer purchases 3 services, then you have to repeat the customer in 2 extra rows just to check if it is billed or not, hence my suggestion would be to have 2 extra rows (billed_1, billed_2, billed_3)

Comment: See `COALESCE()` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
tbl_rendered_services
+----+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | customer | service1_ref | service2_ref | service3_ref | billed_1 | billed_2 | billed_3 |
+----+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 1        | 00001        | 10002        | NULL         | 0        | 0        | 0        |
+----+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 2        | NULL         | 10003        | 20003        | 0        | 0        | 1        |
+----+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

You can see that like this I do not have duplicates.

Comment: Nice suggestion!
But I am thinking, what happens if a customer for example has several unbilled service1_refs? 
Then we would still need two rows in the table to describe this, and we'd have to store a redundant `tinyint` for each service_ref-column that has no reference, and this might end up exeeding the cost of just storing the null-pointers and having one row and one billed-column per service_ref, given that the index is on the customer. Now I'm just rambling. Thank you for your suggestion! I will do more research on the subject :)!